# switching my app from http to https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https

i'm working on an extranet for my school, in php and mysql, running on apache2 and using friendly urls via mod_rewrite.

I'm thinking that since there is potentially sensitive data involved, it would be better to work on an https url rather than http. The thing is: i have absolutely no experience in https. The pros, the cons and will my app actually work or will i need to modify it?

Does it also mean i have to set up something specific on the server? Will it not break the mod_rewrite rules?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your app, everything is the same but the URL.

But the Apache must be configured to properly handle it. Its just another VirtualHost entry in `httpd-vhosts.conf`, but using port 443 and...

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "/..path../certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/..path../certificate.key"
DocumentRoot ...
```

`httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

[Search Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+server.crt+server.key) for instructions of how to create your 'testing purpose' SSL certificate.

Comment: thanks a lot, very helpful. One more thing: do i need to modify mysql and php respective ini files?

Comment: No, its completely transparent for PHP and MySQL.